# Why UITableView first row is behind top tab bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I don't know how to explain my problem therefore I added to screenshots. When I go to personal tab my first row is behind Personal tab and some parts are hided behind it.

[image]

**But when I scroll down I can see them!**

[image]

I have defined tab title in this way:

```
self.title = @"Personal";
```

Any idea why this behave like this?

Comment: I'm thinking it's because the transparent navigation bar of iOS 7/8+... try selecting your navigation controller and in the attributes inspector disable the translucent navigation bar. EDIT: By default, all views pass below the translucent navigation bar. It's by design of the OS.

Comment: this has nothing to do with how you set the title but it has to do with how you have layed out your navigation system and table view. you need to show that code for help

Comment: @AlejandroIván Thanks mate. I just change it to "Opaque Navigation Bar" and problem solved

Comment: Glad I could help, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As @AlejandroIván said I have change top bar to this->

[image: enter code here]

Answer (score 0):

why don't try by setting the `contentInset` property for example

some where is `- (void)viewDidLoad` method set it like

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.personalTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(45,0, 40, 0); //give some higher values "top" to set according to your requirement 

  //...rest of the code 
}
```